# Dense set in respect of the $w^*$-topology in the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, systems-of-equations

Suppose that $V$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and $V^*$ is the dual space, namely the vector space of all linear functionals. Since $V^*$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^V$, give $\mathbb{R}^V$ the product topology and call the relative topology of $V^*$ the $w^*$-topology. I am dealing with the following question.

*Suppose that $W$ is a subspace of $V^*$ such that for every non-zero $x\in V$, there are some $g\in W$ such that $g\left(x\right)\neq 0$, then $W$ is dense in $V^*$.*

**My attempt :**
For every $f\in V^*$, we shall construct a net in $W$ that converges to $f$. To do this, put $\mathcal {F}$ as the collection of all finite subgroups of $V$ directed by $\supset$. For every $A\in \mathcal{F}$, write $A=\left\{x_1,x_2\cdots,x_n\right\}$. If we are able to find a $g_A\in W$ such that $g_A$ and $f$ are identical on $A$, then the net $\left\{g_A:A\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$ converges to $f$, and hence $W$ is dense in $V^*$.

Hence what we need to do is to find $g_A$ for every $A\in\mathcal{F}$. Without loss of generality, suppose that the members of $A$ are linear independent. For for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$, put $f\left(x_i\right)=y_i$  and choose  $g_i\in W$ such that $g_i\left(x_i\right)\neq 0$. Write $g_i\left(x_j\right)=a_{ji}$ for $i,j=1,2,\cdots,n$. If we are able to find a solution $X$ for the equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11}&a_{12}  & \cdots  &a_{1n} \\
  a_{21}&a_{22}  & \cdots  &a_{2n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots  &  &\vdots  \\
  a_{n1}&a_{n2}  & \cdots  &a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}X=\begin{bmatrix}
 y_1\\
 y_2\\
\vdots  \\
y_n
\end{bmatrix}.$$
If a solution $X=\begin{bmatrix}
  c_1\\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n
\end{bmatrix}$ is found, then since $W$ is a subspace, $g_A=\sum^n_{i=1}c_ig_i\in W$. Thus my question is: how to prove that this equation has got some solutions, or, how to establish $g_A$ in some other ways?

Comment: Is $V^\ast$ the space of all linear forms or of all *continuous* linear forms? Typically the star is reserved for continuous forms (=functional) and I’ve seen $V^{\times}$ used for the space of all (potentially discontinuous) linear forms

Comment: My hunch is that you can wlog take $g(x_1)\neq0$ and $g(x_i)=0$ for all other $i$

Comment: @FShrike Yes, I mean the set of all linear functionals.

Comment: @FShrike How can we prove that such $g$ exists?

Comment: I don’t know to be honest. It was just a hunch but it might be false. However note this: you actually only need to get *close* to the values of $f$. This is not about pointwise equality but rather a topological closeness. Maybe pointwise equality can be achieved, but it’s not necessary. Might help

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for your advice, I will have a try.

Comment: I’ve had another thought. You can try to show the kernel of the above matrix is zero, or at least, that you can *choose* the $g_j$ such that it is zero, by considering that the rows/columns are linearly dependent iff. $\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\cap\bigcap_{j=1}^n\ker g_j\neq\{0\}$ (this uses the fact that wlog $x_i$ are linearly independent. If the kernel is trivial then $X$ can always be found, if the kernel is nontrivial then $X$ can’t, in general, be found.

Comment: @FShrike Yes, I have also conceived such and idea. However, the problem is, we can not make sure that, in $V^*$, the $g_i$;s we have chosen are linearly independent. For example, if $g_1$ is non-zero at both $x_1$ and $x_2$, it is possible that $g_2$ is chosen to be $g_1$. And in this case, the columns of the matrix will always be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual of the locally convex space $V^*$ (endowed with the relative topology of $\mathbb R^V$) is the space of all evaluations $\delta_x:V^*\to\mathbb R$, $f\mapsto f(x)$. The Hahn-Banach theorem implies that a subspace $W$ of $V^*$ is dense if and only if only the zero functional on $V^*$ vanishes on $W$, that is, $\delta_x(g)=g(x)=0$ for all $g\in W$ implies $x=0$. This is precisely your assumption on $W$.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I really appreciate it.